# modificar variable mostrada en el HTML desde JS

Tags: javascript, html, variables

[image: Mi Pagina test]

Hola gente, como ven en la página, hay un botón, en el cual clickeo y incrementa la variable `credit` que se muestra en la consola, pero lo que quiero es que esa variable también incremente en donde se encuentra el número 1 que se encuentra en la página al lado de créditos, ya que no se actualiza la variable, así está el script:

```
<script>
    var credit = 0;
    function addCredit(){
            credit = credit + 1;
    }

    addCredit();

    document.write("Creditos ", credit);
</script>
```

Y el botón:

```
<button onclick="addCredit()">Free Credits</button>
```

Seria una gran ayuda quien me respondiera sobre el problema, soy nuevo en la programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero haberte entendido bien y que te sea de ayuda!

```js
var numero = 0;

function incrementar() {
  let elementoDondeMostrar = document.getElementById("mensaje"); // Obtengo el elemento donde voy a mostrar el mensaje
  elementoDondeMostrar.innerHTML  = "Creditos " + numero; // Le pongo el contenido
  numero++; // Incremento la variable
}
```

```html
<h5 id="mensaje"></h5>
<button onclick="incrementar()">Incrementa</button>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

solo es cuestion de que cambies el innerHTML donde quieres que se actualice.

```
 credits.innerHTML=credit;
```

ejemplo:

```js
var credit = 0;


    function addCredit(){

        credit = credit + 1;
        credits.innerHTML=credit;

    }

    addCredit();
```

```html
<p>Créditos <span id='credits'></span><p>
<button onclick="addCredit()">Free Credits</button>
```